# Slicing a 2D list in Python based on match of a regular expression

Tags: python, arrays, regex

I have a 2D array that has many rows and two columns. I want to extract all the rows of this 2D array, in which the first column has a string that matches any of the substrings in a list.

Please see the contrived example below.

```
students_mat = [['Ant', 'Bat', 'Cat', 'Dog', 'Ear'] , [3.75, 4.32, 2.43, 3.73,  2.51]]


subset_ids = ['A', 'B', 'E']
```

I want the output

```
 accepted_std = [['Ant', 'Bat', 'Ear'] , [3.75, 4.32, 2.51]]
```

I tried

```
accepted_std = [s for s in students_mat if any(xs in s for xs in subset_ids)]
```

This does not work, though it works for a 1D list.

Thanks & Regards,
santosh

Comment: None of the subset ids are in `[3.75, 4.32, 2.43, 3.73, 2.51]`. What are the rules for filtering those elements?

Answer (score 2):

```
students_mat = [['Ant', 'Bat', 'Cat', 'Dog', 'Ear'] , [3.75, 4.32, 2.43, 3.73,  2.51]]
subset_ids = ['A', 'B', 'E']

# we need corresponding pairs from first and second subarrays
pairs = zip(*students_mat)

# filtering
filtered_pairs = ((x, y) for x, y in pairs if x[0] in subset_ids)

# returning to original form
original = zip(*filtered_pairs)

# converting to list of lists
accepted_std = list(map(list, original))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
students_mat = [['Ant', 'Bat', 'Cat', 'Dog', 'Ear'] , [3.75, 4.32, 2.43, 3.73,  2.51]]
subset_ids = ['A', 'B', 'E']
indicies = [i for i, a in enumerate(students_mat[0]) if a[0] in subset_ids]
final_data = [[c for i, c in enumerate(a) if i in indicies] for a in students_mat]
```

Output:

```
[['Ant', 'Bat', 'Ear'], [3.75, 4.32, 2.51]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to translate the two lists into a list of tuples, then translate them back into two lists:

```
accepted_std = zip(*
  [
    (txt, num) for (txt, num) in zip(students_mat[0], students_mat[1])
     if any(xs in txt for xs in subset_ids)
 ]
)
```

You can create a list of tuples from a simple list using the `zip` command:

```
for (txt, num) in zip(students_map[0], students_map[1])
```

Then you can filter on the `txt` variable using the same method you did before:

```
if any(xs in txt for xs in subset_ids)
```

Finally, you need to unzip the list of tuples. The `zip(*list)` is exactly for this.